# play framework 2.0 console error

Tags: playframework-2.0

When trying to run the new play 2.0 console (typing 'play' in cmd)
on windows from project folder (as instructed by framework web tutorial).

i receive :

```
C:\temp\play-2.0\play-2.0\todolist>play
[info] Loading project definition from C:\temp\play-2.0\play-2.0\todolist\projec
t
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.types
afe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.hibernate/hibernate-validator/4.2.0.Final/ivys
/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.types
afe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/javax.validation/validation-api/1.0.0.GA/ivys/ivy.
xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.types
afe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.springframework/spring-context/3.0.7.RELEASE/i
vys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.types
afe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.springframework/spring-core/3.0.7.RELEASE/ivys
/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out: connect url=http://repo.types
afe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/org.springframework/spring-beans/3.0.7.RELEASE/ivy
s/ivy.xml
```

list goes on and on...

what is wrong , and why is it trying to access remote locations when all i want to do is use console/run app ?

Comment: Well I'm no help here, but I opened this ticket on their bug tracker: https://play.lighthouseapp.com/projects/82401-play-20/tickets/318-play-console-times-out-on-startup

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I had the same problem, I resolved it by modifying the last line of `build.bat` file in `play/framework`  like this :

java **-Dhttp.proxyUser=*MyProxyAccount* -Dhttp.proxyPassword=*MyProxyPwd* -Dhttp.proxyHost=*MyProxyIp* -Dhttp.proxyPort=*MyProxyPort*** -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*

Hope this help.

Comment: The same is happening with me but not for all dependencies. It shows the error for org.scala-lang#jline;2.10.4 Please help

Answer (score 2):

Are you connected to the internet when you type the command `play`?

Ivy is a dependency manager, and it creates a local repository for dependencies used to build a project.

Comment: i am connected but behind a firewall which i cannot control/disable. i think that unless i request to update from a repository it shouldn't do so automatically. (from about 80mb+ of framework it should work out of the box)

Comment: I am not even able to browse to that location from my browser that's definitely connected to the  internet

Answer (score 2):

I was connected via a proxy and it did not have any user name or password. I edited the last line of the build.bat file in play/framework folder to :

java -Dhttp.proxyHost=EnterHostNameHere -Dhttp.proxyPort=EnterPortNumberHere -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*

Hope this works..! :)