# Getting a console error in Play framework 2.2

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

Getting an error in console while Play framework 2.2, why?

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=10.30.1.3 -Dhttp.proxyPort=3128 -Xms512M -Xmx1024M -Xss1M -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:MaxPermSize=256M %DEBUG_PARAM% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -Dplay.version="%PLAY_VERSION%" -Dsbt.ivy.home="%~dp0..\repository" -Dplay.home="%~dp0." -Dsbt.boot.properties="file:///%p%sbt/sbt.boot.properties" -jar "%~dp0sbt\sbt-launch.jar" %*
```

Comment: others might have difficulties in helping you unless you elaborate more.. have you checked this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759815/play-framework-2-0-console-error

Comment: My error is like this.

Comment: Yes i have have checked that. I can't post the whole error i'm getting because site doesn't allow me to do that. I did that but it has cropped the best part of my question.. I'm getting a server access error like in the link you mentioned. I have set the HTTP_Proxy and edited build.bat file . But still the same error.