# Why does Activator finish with Server access Error: Operation timed out?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, sbt, typesafe-activator

I have created a project with Typesafe Activator 1.2.2, but my computer cannot resolve dependencies. I use Scala. I have a Mac with Mavericks (I had the same problem with Snow Leopard).

The strange thing is that my project works perfectly fine on my Linux home computer, so I don't understand why there is a problem on my mac. Here is the log:

```
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-jshint;1.0.0 ...
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-jshint/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn]          module not found: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-jshint;1.0.0
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releases: tried
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-jshint/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== sbt-plugin-releases: tried
[warn] http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-jshint/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== local: tried
[warn] /Users/jjuulliieenn/.ivy2/local/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-jshint/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== activator-local: tried
[warn] file:/Users/jjuulliieenn/Documents/Elia/elia/repository/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-jshint/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== public: tried
[warn] http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-jshint_2.10_0.13/1.0.0/sbt-jshint-1.0.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-releases: tried
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-jshint_2.10_0.13/1.0.0/sbt-jshint-1.0.0.pom
[warn] ==== typesafe-ivy-releasez: tried
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-jshint/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[warn] ==== Typesafe repository: tried
[warn] http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/com/typesafe/sbt/sbt-jshint_2.10_0.13/1.0.0/sbt-jshint-1.0.0.pom
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-rjs;1.0.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Operation timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-rjs/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
```

Here is [Full Log](http://textup.fr/96833kz).

Comment: `Server access Error: Operation timed out...` Probably says it all. Seems like it's having trouble with the scala-sbt repo. Has this been happening consistently (more than one day)?

Comment: I've installed activator two weeks ago and for that moment, I have this problem. I've tried different internet connexions but it changed nothing.

Comment: Are you able to access the timed out URL through your browser?

Comment: No, I'm not. I can access to it through my home PC but not from my mac laptop. I use the same internet connexion and I have no proxy activated.

Comment: Can you execute `curl -L http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-jshint/scala_2.10/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml` from the command line to ensure that you can at least access the file outside sbt/activator?

Comment: possible duplicate of [play framework 2.0 console error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9759815/play-framework-2-0-console-error)

Comment: Here is the log for the curl problem : 
curl: (7) Failed connect to dl.bintray.com:80; Operation timed out

I've seen the last post but I don't use proxy and I use scala not java

Comment: I finally found a solution : I did an ifconfig and I turned down all the interfaces I don't need. Now, it works but I still don't understand where was the problem.

Comment: Would you mind adding the last comment as an answer and approve (so the question gets removed from the list of unanswered ones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution : I did an ifconfig and I turned down all the interfaces I don't need. Now, it works but I still don't understand where was the problem.