# typesafe activator dependency error

Tags: scala, playframework, typesafe-activator, typesafe

I just download the last activator version (version 1.2.12 - offline distribution) and I have found some errors in dependency when I follow the documentation in order to create a new scala project (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/NewApplication).

How can I get the unresolved dependency?
Can I install like mvn:install the missing dependency?

```
[info] Updating {file:/home/myhome/workspaceScala/play-scala/project/}play-scala-build...
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#routes-compiler_2.10;2.3.8 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.3.8/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/routes-compiler_2.10/2.3.8/jars/routes-compiler_2.10.jar
[info] Resolving commons-io#commons-io;2.0.1 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/commons-io/commons-io/2.0.1/ivys/ivy.xml
[info] Resolving com.typesafe.play#sbt-run-support_2.10;2.3.8 ...
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support_2.10/2.3.8/ivys/ivy.xml
[error] Server access Error: Connection timed out url=http://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-run-support_2.10/2.3.8/jars/sbt-run-support_2.10.jar
```

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/a/12002136/3841803

Comment: Its clearly an error indicating some sort of network problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you singhakash and Sarvesh, it is a network problem.

I think the best solution is to set environment variable ACTIVATOR_OPTS.
I add this line to my .bashrc file (~/.bashrc):

```
export ACTIVATOR_OPTS="-Dhttp.proxyUser=MyProxyAccount -Dhttp.proxyPassword=MyProxyPwd -Dhttp.proxyHost=MyProxyIp -Dhttp.proxyPort=MyProxyPort"
```

Thanks a lot